# How did the DC power stations work

Tags: power

I've been reading about the great [War of Currents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_of_Currents) and I've been trying to find out how DC power was generated in great volumes. I can't imagine it was with dozens of chemical cells, but I can't find information on it.

A secondary question is about how Edison planned to generate DC from Niagra falls -- I can't see how to generate anything but AC from that.

Comment: I have a lot of DC devices at home that are not powered by batteries...

Comment: What are they powered by? And saying "An AC/DC converter" is not an answer! :-)

Comment: Of course it is an answer, because that is what they are powered by. What else did you expect? unicorns? fairies?

Comment: @DavidBoshton - Maxwell's Demons.

Comment: I guess my incredulity came from the fact that since AC is clearly superior, why would you produce AC and then convert to DC for transmission? Makes no sense. It seems that the only driving force for the technology was the fact that Edison had the patents.

Answer (score 3):

Look up [dynamos](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamo), and if you really want details I'm sure there are copies of the original patents somewhere.

Here's another interesting [link](http://www.edisontechcenter.org/generators.html) with some history, diagrams and videos.

Comment: Basically a dynamo is an AC generator with a mechanical commutator switching the output connections to maintain a particular polarity.

Comment: Thanks for that. The mind boggles; why on earth would you add the commutator? I'm assuming they smoothed it, otherwise why not add transformers?

Comment: You would need to do some reading about Edison and Tesla to understand the history.  For now, let's just say that DC was invented first and the first devices to convert rotary motion to power were DC devices.  These were called either a Generator or Dynamo, depending on which side of the pond you lived.  DC power was king in Edison's day until this young upstart named Tesla came along and single-handedly created the power system that we take for granted today.

Comment: Must of been tough building all those generating stations by hand and pulling all that cable :)

Comment: Actually, the AC generator was first, credited to Pixii in 1833. Its being AC was seen as a problem at the time, solved by the later invention of the commutator.